# Determine for which real k the range of this matrix is 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm studying for finals and this exercise showed up:

*Determine for which real values of $k$ the matrix $A$ = $B^3$ is quivalent by rows to a matrix of the type*

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & a\\0 & 1 &b\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ where $B=  
\begin{bmatrix}1&k^2+k&1\\-k&k^2&k\\k&k&-k\end{bmatrix}$

I interpret this as for what values of k, range$(A)= 2$. But I have no idea which properties I can use so that I don't have to find $B^3$

Any suggestions?

Comment: hmmm $\det A = 0 \implies \det B = 0,  \det B = -2(k^3 + k^2)\implies k = 0, -1$  But for each of these I do not get the correct form for $B^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\det A=\det B =0\\
\det\begin{bmatrix}1&k^2+k&1\\-k&k^2&k\\k&k&-k\end{bmatrix}\\
= \det\begin{bmatrix}1&k^2+k&1\\-k&k^2&k\\0&k^2+k&0\end{bmatrix} \quad(R_3\to R_2+R_3)\\
= -(k^2+k)\det\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-k&k\end{bmatrix}=-2k^2(k+1)=0$$

So $k=0$ or $k=-1$.  When $k=0$, the second and third row $B$ becomes zero, so the row rank of $B$ is $1$, while that of $A$ is two, contradiction.  We are left with $k=-1$.  Check that this satisfies the given conditions.

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\1&1&-1\\-1&-1&1\end{bmatrix},$$
but $$B^3=\begin{bmatrix}-3&-3&-3\\6&3&0\\-6&-3&0\end{bmatrix},$$
which is row equivalent to 
$$\begin{bmatrix}-3&-3&-3\\6&3&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},$$
so we are done.

Comment: But if the range of B is 2, must the range of $B^3$ also be 2?

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio $0\le\mathrm{rank}(B^3)\le\mathrm{rank}(B)$  In the case $k=0$, $\mathrm{rank}(B)=1$, so $\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank}(B^3)\le1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Ohhh I didn't know that property. Does it always hold that rank$(AB) \le$ rank $(B) \ $ $\forall A \in \mathbb {K}^{n \times n} $ ?

Comment: In fact, for any function you want, since compositing $B$ with $A$ on the left enlarges the inverse image of $0$ ("kernel" in the case of a homomorphism) by adjoining the preimage of $A$.